# Exporting Data from ADAM 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, export, adam

I am trying to get all of the USER data from our current ADAM instance.  We are no longer going to use ADAM.  I'd like to export the user information into a file that can then be imported into a User table in SQL.

I found the tool csvde.exe that comes installed with ADAM, however, I don't seem to know how to get only the users.  It looks like it is giving me a list of containers.

I am on the machine of the ADAM instance I want to get the data from.  I ran the following code:

```
csvde -f OUTPUT.csv
```

I'm not getting the user information I'm looking for.

**UPDATE**

I tried the suggestion below:

```
csvde -f output.csv -r (objectCategory=person)
```

That appeared to generate user information, however, it looks like it is pulling information from all of the AD instances?  (I'm not an AD person, but yet I play one on TV.  So I'm not sure what I'm talking about here, it is just my observations).  It appears that the above command pulled down production AD users.

I'm running this command on a dev box and I really just want the instance that is on the box that I'm on.  I try to use the -s command but it stats that "the connection cannot be established".

```
csvde -f output.csv -r (objectCategory=person) -s appdevbox
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the following a try:

`csvde -f output.csv -r (objectCategory=person)`

That should give you only objects that are of an objectCategory of "person", which should include only your users.

Comment: That appeared to work but it looks like it exported production?  I'm not sure.  I'm trying to do this from my DEV box and I got a lot more records then what I'm seeing in my adsiedit console.  Is there anyway to limit just to the box that I'm on?